# Use Windows Authentication in combination with a IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication, claims-based-identity

I want to create a .NET 7 MVC Web Application.

For authentication I want to use Windows and/or Active Directory. There should be no login and passwords. This method should only be used to identify/authenticate a user.

In the next step I want to use a IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory to read all relevant data for the logged in user and store them in Claims.
The IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory should read the data from my database (preferably via Dapper).

One of the things I added in my startup is the following, but it's not even noted during execution.

> builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory, MyClaimPrincipalFactory>();

In my iisSettings I have windowsAuthentication set to true and anonymousAuthentication set to false.

I have already looked at some examples of this and implemented them myself.
For example, a new empty MVC project with "Individual Authentication".
Each of them uses a login form with name and password.
There the use of the IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory works. However, I want to avoid the use of passwords. Among other things, I also considered using IClaimsTransformation. However, it seems that these options do not work when using Windows authentication.

Other configurations I have added.

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<MyClaimsFactory>();
    

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.Ntlm);
```

Can you tell me if this is even possible or am I missing an important part in the configuration? Has anyone already implemented it and can give me an explanation?